# Executar 2 queries ao mesmo tempo é possivel?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Preciso alterar todos os campos de uma tabela e inserir somente em uma linha outro resultado. Estou usando o seguinte codigo

```
 $Nid = intval($_GET['Nid']);

$sql = "UPDATE * FROM programacao SET status='offline' WHERE status ='online' ";
$sql2 = "UPDATE programacao SET status='online' WHERE Nid = :Nid";
try {

  $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
  $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql2);
  $stmt->bindValue(":Nid", $Nid);

   $stmt->execute();
```

O código está funcionando porém executa somente a segunda query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse comportamento é o esperado, a segunda consulta sobrescreve o valor de `$stmt`, você pode resolver isso de duas formas, criar dois prepared statemetns ou chamar duas vezes o `excute()` repectivamente após o `prepare()`

Opção 1

```
$stmt1 = $DB->prepare($sql);  
$stmt2 = $DB->prepare($sql2);
$stmt2->bindValue(":Nid", $Nid);

$stmt1->execute();    
$stmt2->execute();
```

Opção 2

```
$stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();    

$stmt->closeCursor();

$stmt = $DB->prepare($sql2);
$stmt->bindValue(":Nid", $Nid);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: fiz exatamente a opcao 2, funcionou perfeito valeu